# SQL Server - Filter data using a query which is dependent on another query

Tags: sql-server, join

I have a query which returns few emmployee id's and the query looks like below

```
select E.EmpID as EmployeeID
from tblEmployee E
where EmpRole in (1,2,3) and E.Test like '%PS%'
```

I have another query which looks like below one

```
Select E.EmpID and EmployeeID, B.CountryId, B.CountryName, B.StateId, 
B.StateName
from tblEmployeeInfo E
inner join tblTest B
where E.StateId = B.StateId and E.CountryId = B.CountryId
```

My requirement is that the second query needs to return data of only those employees which are resulted in 1st query...

Both are different tables, how can i join these both ?

Comment: Hi. This is (obviously) a faq. Which like most faqs will be found by doing what should be done before considering posting re any question/problem/goal--google many clear concise precise phrasings of it with & without specific strings. Duplicates should not be posted & if posted should be linked & not answered. See [ask] & the downvote arrow mouseover text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a Select inside the IN clause

```
Select E.EmpID as EmployeeID, B.CountryId, B.CountryName, B.StateId, 
B.StateName
from tblEmployeeInfo E
inner join tblTest B
where E.StateId = B.StateId and E.CountryId = B.CountryId
and E.EmpID IN (select E.EmpID
    from tblEmployee E
    where EmpRole in (1,2,3) and E.Test like '%PS%'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do another JOIN in tblEmployee :

```
Select E.EmpID and EmployeeID, B.CountryId, B.CountryName, B.StateId, 
B.StateName
from tblEmployeeInfo E
JOIN tblTest B ON E.StateId = B.StateId and E.CountryId = B.CountryId
JOIN tblEmployee E2 ON E.EmpID = E2.EmpID AND E2.EmpRole in (1,2,3) AND E2.Test like '%PS%'
```